# Drupal - rules - if URL is present

Tags: drupal

Ive setup the following rule in Drupal:

**NOT condition** - Logged in user has his Profile created
**DO condition** - Redirect user to profile creation page

But I only want this rule to run, if the following is present in the URL.

**user?destination=og%2Fsubscribe%2F67**  ( this forwards users to the group after the register, o allow the to reqest a join)

The reason for wanting this, is because I also have logintoboggan setup, which forwards all new user to a specific page, after registration, which takes them through their setup. But I dont want users who have been asked to join a group, to follow this same procudure, which is why I have setup the rule.  But unfortunatelly the rule overrides logintoboggan.

Which is why I want to somehow tell the rules module to only run this rule, when **"user?destination=og"** is present in the URL

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition using a custom PHP statement.

```
return arg(0) == "user" && $_GET['destination'] == "og/subscribe/67';
```

If you want to check just whether og is in the destination, you could modify it to

```
return arg(0) == "user" && stripos($_GET['destination'], "og") !== FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or install the [Path Rules module](https://drupal.org/project/pathrules).